# How am I misusing the start with selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

if `a == "http://foo.bar"`
and `$(b[0]).attr("href") == "http://foo.bar"`

then why does the following code not return true:

```
$("[href^=\"" + a + "\"]", b).length > 0
```

?

Comment: Are you missing a pair of quotes in the last line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the second parameter passed to the jQuery function scopes the selector, which is to say, find the selected element in the *children* of b.

So by way of an example

```
<div id="one">
   <div id="two" title="Test" />
</div>
```

This will return 1

```
$('[title="Test"]','#one').length
```

This will return 0

```
$('[title="Test"]','#two').length
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/mkudf/

---

Based on your comments, it seems you're doing some stuff before adding the element to the dom, so by example:

```
var $x = $('<div id="one" /><div id="two" title="Test" />');
alert($('[title="Test"]',$x).length); // alerts "0"
```

I can find no way of achieving what you want (The above to alert "1") without wrapping the dynamic elements in an extra element:

```
var $x = $('<div><div id="one" /><div id="two" title="Test" /></div>');
alert($('[title="Test"]',$x).length); // now alerts "1"
```

Which shouldnt be too much of a problem, when adding to the dom you could just take `$x.children()`:

```
$someOtherElement.after($x.children());
```

Comment: I have been assuming that when I create an object with a constructor it is an orphan (not part of the main dom structure) until I add it in.  If that is the case, how do I restrict the search of the selector to the scope of an array of orphan nodes, without being limited to the children of those nodes?  And if it's not the case, what's the most efficient way to do what I want?

Comment: @RobF - Im not sure I entirely follow. Can you update the question to give a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Let's say we take your example, only 'two' isn't inside of 'one' but rather adjascent to it, and then there are a few more, in an array.  How does one limit a selector to searching among these nodes?